# Need to Pull Data from Second Sheet using Part of Cell on First Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am manipulating data created by another program and saved into Excel, and that data is NOT consistent in the way that some things are abbreviated, nor on the spacing in some of the cells. This site has helped a lot with pulling out some of the data, but this one has me stumped. If it's already been answered, please point me to that answer, as I couldn't find it. :)

I have a "reference" worksheet (that stays hidden) where the first column is possible abbreviations, and the second column is the value that needs to be returned. The reference sheet might show: (cells seperated by //, rows separated by \: Apple//Apple\  Apple//Apple\  Banana//Banana\  Ban//Banana\  Org//Orange\  Orange//Orange)

[image: ReferenceSheetData]

The created/imported data might include 4 cells that look like this (cells separated by //: 1234 - Apple - Cut and serve //Sometimes 836 Banana Raw//Org Peel // 730-Orange-Juice):

[image: ImportedData]

I need to pull out the name of the fruit referenced in each. Effectively, what I need is the row (on the reference sheet) where the contents of the cell in the first column are included in the data imported. Then, I can use a lookup to pull the value from the cell in the second column of that row.

So, in my sample data, the formula would return:

2
3
5
6

I hope that is clearly explained. Oh, and I can only use formulas, no programming of any sort.

Thanks for any direction you can give.

Comment: Have you tried Replace instead of formulas?

Comment: Hmmm...Replace isn't something I've looked at AT ALL yet. The problem is that I don't know which abbreviation will be in the imported data, and the abbreviations may change over time, so the spreadsheet needs to be referencing a sheet that can be easily edited at a later date. Also, the data from the other program can't be edited (it's saved in a different spreadsheet that lots of people access). And one last complicating detail: I have one abbreviation that is part of another abbreviation (like "ap" for apple being part of the word grape).

Comment: not sure if this will work in all cases, but Ap for Apple is only found at the start of Apple so if you were Searching for Ap you might search for " Ap" (Ap with a leading space).  Would not help if you were using Br for Brussel Sprouts and you have Broccoli to contend with as well

Comment: is there only 1 fruit named in each cell?  so you would not see something like 1234 - Apple and Orange - Cut and Serve

Comment: The issues mentioned also apply to the formula solution, you'll always need to delimit the characters combination both at the beginning and at the end of it to ensure the combination found is not a partial of another word. This calls for adding a blank space at the beginning and at the end of each cell. I suggest to go for a VBA solution.

Comment: Forward Ed, 

1) There isn't always a leading space before the text I'm searching for, unfortunately.

2) There is only one fruit in each cell.

Comment: EEM, I'm using fruit as an example, but the abbreviations that I'm actually searching for are extremely unlikely to be part of any other word, and certainly not at the beginning of the data in the cell I'm searching. The samples I gave may not reflect the data as well as I'd like. The imported data I'm searching SHOULD start with a trigger word (or two) and a date, then the "fruit" that I need to pull out of the data.

Also, the company has specifically forbidden any programming. They don't even allow macros. :(

Comment: What about this: **And one last complicating detail: I have one abbreviation that is part of another abbreviation (like "ap" for apple being part of the word grape)**   As regards the use of macros, so macros are are not allowed even for personal working files? *i.e. a macro residing a separated file located in your computer or your flashcard which is used only to improve your task in regards to performance, efficiency and accuracy?*

Comment: I know that this would probably be pretty simple in VBA. Does a subroutine like this exist somewhere that I could have a look at just for information? I know VERY little about VBA, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no way for do this with a formula if you import the data as you show because you can't do a "search" for each "substring" (or word) contained in a cell comparing it with a list of other substrings.
Otherwise if you import the data of the "created/imported" sheet specifyng as cell-separator the space " " and as row separator the "//" you will have a single word for each cell, like

```
    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    |    F    |    G    |  
  1234        -       apple       -        cut      and       serve  
sometimes   836       banana     raw  
  org       peel  
  730      orange     juice
```

here you can use the `VLOOKUP` for every cell of the columns formed with the import for search the word in the "reference" sheet, so use the same amount of cols (in this case 7) and for each cell of the cols do the `VLOOKUP` for the corresponding cell (A to G in the example) and find your friut, with something like this

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;'[Worksheet_reference.xlsx]sheet_reference'!$A$1:$A$100;2;FALSE)
```

you can obtain something like

```
  AA    |    AB    |    AC    |     AD    |    AE    |    AF    |    AG    |  
 N/A        N/A        apple       N/A       N/A         N/A        N/A  
 N/A        N/A       banana       N/A  
orange      N/A  
 N/A       orange     N/A
```

you can add an `IF` with an `ISNA` for detect the N/A values and write something else instead of them, for example

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1;'[Worksheet_reference.xlsx]sheet_reference'!$A$1:$A$100;2;FALSE));"";VLOOKUP(A1;'[Worksheet_reference.xlsx]sheet_reference'!$A$1:$A$100;2;FALSE))
```

for return "" instead of N/A, and then you can concatenate the results (you said there is only one friut for each row) all the rows for have the result in one single row, like in cell `AF`

```
=AA&AB&AC&AD&AE&AF&AE
```

you will obtain only the friuts...
This is not so "clean", but it's the only way i can imagine ;)

Ettore